# SSRS Report Parameters and Report Setup System

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've got a front-end application that pulls a report on top of SQL lives "Report Setup System" software that pulls the specific SSRS template/parameters that pass them to SQL procedure.

the report path specifies a given SSRS file, and no parameters are being passed to this file.

When I open the SSRS file it requires 4 parameters which it then passes to 3 sub/nested reports.  The SQL behind the SSRS report file requires 4 parameters and doesn't allow the use of default data. however, i can't locate where these are being set in SSRS/Visual studio.

The parameters set up in the main report doesn't have any default data - these are hidden (they don't appear on the report), available values are None, default values are "no default value", and under advanced "automatically determine when to refresh" where are these being set?? Please advise where to look.

Comment: I personally cannot figure out what is the "Report setup system", could you explain that to me a little bit? If you go into the report and into preview, how many parameters does it let you input? I would go back to the other tab and explore the dataset. How many datasets are there? Is there a dataset gathering the parameter values? Typically myself I have one big dataset that is a stored procedure, then many small ones that collect dynamic parameters that i am going to pass to that main dataset and my stored procedure parameters will match.

Comment: the software we use - is called "gsrsetup" or "report set up utility connection" and the long version is its a set up software for the primary application we've got. I wish I had more information on it. This is the software where we build the link between the SSRS files and the primary software application. This is where we set up parameters and SSRS file path. The software doesn't let you input any parameters which is the strange part - usually this is where parameters are entered. But the dataset is expecting 4 parameters as I mentioned and won't work on NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can pass values to report parameters.
Assuming that you are using processing mode is 'remote',
you have to look for something like following in your code, to see values being passed:

```
ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("ShowDescriptions", checkBox1.Checked.ToString());
reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
```

**Ref**: (MSDN) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252178(v=vs.140).aspx

Another way to pass parameters to report is via URL 
[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters..](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/)

**In a nutshell**, you may need to *look* into the *code*, and not only into properties and settings of the report parameters, to actually *ascertain* what's going on : )

Comment: where would I look for this code, in SSRS/visual studio or the report set up software?

Comment: Visual studio should point you to the database code then go modify db code to work with default values?

Comment: @Elizabeth Interestingly, the Visual Studio Data Tools, or Report Builder come as Visual Studio Shell, and looks like normal Visual Studio  but that's _not_ the actual point to start. Preferably, you should start from the solution/project where your actual C#, or VB.NET (whatever) code lies, as that's the place where your report should be getting called from.

Comment: I've sorted out the issue -- the parameters are set on the server where the actual, SSRS file lives. So if no parameters are passed from the report set up then the default ones on the server are executed.